# How to set focus on input field in Clarity modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, vmware-clarity

I am using Clarity 3 and Angular 9. I have Modal window with one input field. When modal is opened the input field should be in focused state.

Here is code for my modal window:

```html
<clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="modal">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I have a nice title</h3>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This input should get the focus when modal is opened.</p>
        <input class="clr-input" type="text" #input>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="close()">Close</button>
    </div>
</clr-modal>
```

The problem is Clarity does not provide callback when modal is opened. If I try to set focus in the method `open()`, then I couldn't do this because by this time the modal window had not yet opened due to animation.

```
@ViewChild('input', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;

open() {
    this.modal = true;
    this.input.nativeElement.focus(); // does not work
}
```

If I set some delay with `setTimeout`, when it works, but I don't like such solution.

```
setTimeout(() => this.input.nativeElement.focus(), 10);
```

I also tried to use directive `clrFocusOnViewInit`, but it also doesn't work.

```
<input class="clr-input" type="text" #input [clrFocusOnViewInit]="true">
```

Can someone suggest me a good solution? Why the directive `clrFocusOnViewInit` does not work?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-focus-on-view-init

**Update**

I created a feature request in Clarity project:
https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4476

Answer (score 0):

Using `clrFocusOnViewInit` doesn't work in this case because it is already used by the modal to focus on the modal title. This is per our accessibility design and research to ensure that all users can properly use the modal. If you opt to go against this, it could have consequences for some users and accessibility compliance.

Clarity provides an output when the opened state changes, but it fires immediately and not after the modal animates in. Any two way binding can be deconstructed to the following to get the input and output separately. `<clr-modal [clrModalOpen]="modal" (clrModalOpenChange)="onOpen()">`

If you must change the focus, then you'll be able to listen to the open change event, and you could set a timeout of 1100ms and move the focus then.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I approve your approach to set focus on modal window when it has opened, but in my case it would be more friendly for user to set focus in input field directly.

And I still don't understand how to do this without setTimeout. Yes, I know about that dual binding is just syntax sugar, but output event does not fire when modal window became opened.

Comment: I created a feature request:
https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4476

Answer (score 0):

try using clrFocusTrap="1" starting from where you want it to be.